# How to Send 401 from custom implementation of OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider

Tags: oauth-2.0, owin, jwt

I will be extremely grateful if someone can shed some light on how can we send appropriate HTTP status codes from our custom implementation of

```
OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
```

I am doing the following

```
context.Rejected()
context.SetError("invalid_grant", "User Name or Password are Not Correct");
return Task.FromResult<object>();
```

This always sends back a 400 response code.

Comment: Can you tell us where in the OAuthServer you use this code? I mean in which handler..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the normal behaviour, implemented in `Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth` dll, when for example the owner credentials are not validated in `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials()` method of `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` class. You cannot override this behaviour.

You will get `401-Unauthorized` response from resource server when the bearer token included in the request is not valid, for example if has expired or the claims inside the ticket don't allow the execution of a particular controller action.